# How to update tags after rebase of entire branch?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Recently I've rebased my `master` branch starting from the root `--root`. For clarity, I visualize it:

```
   v1       v2
    |       |
A---B---C---D (master)
```

Now after running `git rebase --root -i` I have the following:

```
'A---'B---'C---'D (master)

    v1      v2
    |       |
    ?       ?     (old-master)
```

As you can see I just want to update references of `v1` and `v2` to `'B` and `'D` accordingly. How can I do it without using miracle scripts, but built-in git tools?

I've heard that it can be done using `git filter-branch --tag-name-filter`, but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

`git push -f . 'B:v1 && git push -f . 'C:v2` ? `.` means local repo.

Comment: I do not understand your answer. Could you explain please?

Comment: Do you here?) I'm still waiting..)